# ORA-6502, from WEB

Tags: plsql

I have a problem with Oracle DB.

```
 <?php
    require_once 'includes/conn.php';
    function connect_db()
    {
        if ($c=oci_pconnect(uname,pwd, host,'AL32UTF8'))
            return $c;
        else
            die( "ERROR");
    }
    $conn=connect_db();

    $query = "BEGIN :ds_id :=DS.REG_DS1(:F_NAME);END;";
    $stmt=oci_parse($conn,$query);
    $f_name='John Doe';
    $ds_id=-1;

    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":ds_id", $ds_id);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":F_NAME", $f_name);
    if(oci_execute($stmt))
    {
        echo 'good';
    }
    else
        print_r(oci_error($stmt));
?>
```

Here is function REG_DS1

```
FUNCTION REG_DS1(F_NAME IN VARCHAR) RETURN NUMBER AS
  DS_ID NUMBER(8,0):=9988;
BEGIN
--    INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(F_NAME,SYSDATE);
    RETURN DS_ID;
END REG_DS1;
```

When I try to execute this function from Sql Developer, it runs with no problem.
But if I execute from PHP script above, it gives me error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 1 [offset] => 0 [sqltext] => BEGIN :ds_id :=DS.REG_DS1(:F_NAME);END; )
```

If i change DS_ID variable to another number less than 100, it works great from both. but if i set it to a number more than 99, it gets me error from php script.

What can be a problem?

Comment: Alas I know far too little to be of constructive help in answering but, for the record, I removed the 6502 tag because per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/6502 that tag is defined to be for questions related to "[t]he 6502, developed by MOS Technology ... an 8-bit microprocessor", to which I think this ORA-06502 question doesn't relate. Even though by pure coincidence the 6502 8-bit processor has an ORA instruction.

Answer (score 0):

--jst idea and this is not solutioN

variable decleration or some defination problem

```
oci_connect($ODBuser,$ODBpass,$ODBhost,$db_charset);
```

should try like this
**not like**

`oci_pconnect(uname,pwd, host,'AL32UTF8')`

sample code :

```
-- just idea 
<?php

$file = "../script/param.CML";
$encryptObj = new cast128;
$encryptObj->setkey("SABBIllustrateKey");

$fp=fopen($file,'r');
$strContent = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);

$strContent=$encryptObj->decrypt($strContent);

$ArConnect=split("   ",$strContent);
$OraService=$ArConnect[8];
$OraUser=$ArConnect[9];
$OraDBpass=$ArConnect[10];
$db_charset = 'AL32UTF8';


$cursor=oci_connect($OraUser,$OraDBpass,$OraService,$db_charset);

if(!$cursor)
{
 echo "<br>Error In connection:- reason<BR>";
 $e = oci_error();  // For oci_connect errors pass no handle
}
```

?>

---

```
<?php

$file = "../script/param.CML";
$encryptObj = new cast128;
$encryptObj->setkey("SABBIllustrateKey");

$fp=fopen($file,'r');
$strContent = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);

$strContent=$encryptObj->decrypt($strContent);

$con=split("   ",$strContent);
$OraService=$con[8];
$OraUser=$con[9];
$OraDBpass=$con[10];
$db_charset = 'AL32UTF8';


$cursor=oci_connect($OraUser,$OraDBpass,$OraService,$db_charset);

if(!$cursor)
{
 echo "<br>Error In connection:- reason<BR>";
 $e = oci_error();  // For oci_connect errors pass no handle
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx guys, finally I solved problem myself.
The problem was in variable size of returning value

By changing

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":ds_id", $ds_id);
```

to

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":ds_id", $ds_id,10,SQLT_INT );
```

the problem was solved.